# Grails: How to use same domain class for 2 different controllers

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, gsp

This is what I'm attempting to do.

Form1 -> PCController -> PC -> Database

Form2 -> GPCController -> PC -> Database

All the domain classes are mapped to DB

During create/edit, Form2 is getting redirected to PCController and the subsequent show/edit page because the created object is of type PC, it's autowired to that controller.

```
<g:link action="show" controller="gPC" resource="${pCInstance}" params="[noheader: params.noheader]"><g:message code="default.button.show.label" default="Cancel" /></g:link>
```

I tried switching the pCInstance to gPCInstance. The control goes to the GPCController but the gPCInstance isn't the object instance, so it returns null when it hits the GPCController

How do I make this scenario work effeciently?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to such a thing is trivial and you have a few options:

1. Don't declare the controller at all. This will then leave it upon current action to carry out the required action.

   <g:link action="show" resource="${pCInstance}" params="[noheader: params.noheader]">

This will then carry out show in what ever action has renderd that view.

2. a bit similar to option 1 but has other uses:

Declare it as [controllerName](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/grails-goodness-access-action-and.html):

```
<g:link action="show" controller="${controllerName}" resource="${pCInstance}" params="[noheader: params.noheader]"><g:message code="default.button.show.label" default="Cancel" /></g:link>
```

The latter is more useful for figuring out where you are `if actionName == currentAction` and so forth ....

Anyhow be careful with the usage of that but that should guide you in how to solve it and typically this is the approach to dynamic templating around repeated menu options etc